# java.awt.List has inconsistent width

Tags: java, macos, swing, awt

I've a problem with the layout of this applet. Its got a List next to a Canvas in a border layout. Now sometimes when I run it the list is very narrow, 51 pixels wide. Other times with a tiny change in the code it works fine and the list is wide enough to display the entries. The list is populated from an array and commenting out one item from the array is 
enough to change behavior. To be precise commenting this line fixes the problem

```
{"---- Lissajous curves ","t","t","1","1"}, // commenting this line fixes problem
```

I suspect this is a bug, but it would be nice to know if its reproducible or if I'm doing something silly. Also not quite sure of right place to submit a bug, I'm using the standard Java on Mac OS X 10.6.8

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.List;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Zap extends Applet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 330L;

    String[][] equations = new String[][]{
//                  {"Line ----------------------","3 t-1","t+1"},
                    {"Line","3 t-1","t+1"},
                    {"Circle","cos(t)","sin(t)","-pi","pi"},
                    {"Sq Circle","cos(t)","2 sin(t)","-pi","pi"},
                    {"Ellipse","2 cos(t)","sin(t)","-pi","pi"},
                    {"Cycloid","t-sin(t)","1-cos(t)","-20","20"},
                    {"---- Hypocycloids ----"},
                    {"Deltoid","2 cos(t)+cos(2t)","2 sin(t)-sin(2t)","-pi","pi"},
                    {"Astroid","cos(t)^3","sin(t)^3","-pi","pi"},
                    {"Hypocycloids 5","cos(t) + cos(4 t)/4","sin(t) - sin(4 t)/4","-pi","pi" },
                    {"---- Epicycloids ----"},
                    {"Cardioid",
                            "cos(t) - cos(2 t)/2",
                            "sin(t) - sin(2 t)/2","-pi","pi" },
                    {"Nephroid",
                                            "cos(t) - cos(3 t)/3",
                                            "sin(t) - sin(3 t)/3","-pi","pi" },
                    {"Epicycloid 3",
                                                    "cos(t) - cos(4 t)/4",
                                                    "sin(t) - sin(4 t)/4","-pi","pi" },
                    {"Epicycloid 4",
                                                            "cos(t) - cos(5 t)/5",
                                                            "sin(t) - sin(5 t)/5","-pi","pi" },
                    {"Epicycloid 4",
                                                            "cos(t) - cos(5 t)/5",
                                                            "sin(t) - sin(5 t)/5","-pi","pi" },
                    {"Epicycloid 5",
                                                                    "cos(t) - cos(6 t)/6",
                                                                    "sin(t) - sin(6 t)/6","-pi","pi" },

                    {"---- Lissajous curves ","t","t","1","1"}, // commenting this line
                    {"Lissajous 1,2","sin(t)","sin(2 t)","-pi","pi"},
                    {"Lissajous 1,3","sin(t-pi/2)","sin(3 t)","-pi","pi"},
                    {"Lissajous 1,4","sin(t)","sin(4 t)","-pi","pi"},//             {"a Lissajousxxxxxxxxxxb",""},
                    {"Lissajous 2,1","sin(2t)","sin(t)","-pi","pi"},
                    {"Lissajous 2,2","sin(2t-pi/4)","sin(2t)","-pi","pi"},
                    {"Lissajous 2,3","sin(2t-pi/3)","sin(3t)","-pi","pi"},
                    {"Lissajous 3,4","sin(3t)","sin(4t)","-pi","pi"},
    };



    /** The canvas for plotting the graph */
    private Canvas graphCanvas;

    /** List of equations */
    List list = new List();

    /**
     * Initializes the applet FunctionPlotter
     */
    @Override
    public void init ()  {
        try {
            initComponents();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Sets the layout of the applet window to BorderLayout, creates all
     * the components and associates them with event listeners if necessary.
     * @param j
     * @throws JepException
     */
    private void initComponents ()  {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

//        GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1,0.9, 1, GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 , 0) ;
//        GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 0.1, 1, GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0);
//        setBackground (java.awt.Color.white);

//        list.addItemListener(this);
        list.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(220, 200));
        list.setSize(new Dimension(220, 200));
        list.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(220, 200));
        System.out.println("list "+list.getBounds());
        System.out.println("list ps"+list.getPreferredSize());
        //add(list,gbc2);
        add("East",list);
        for(String[] eles:equations) {
            list.add(eles[0]);
    }
        // create the graph canvas and add it
        graphCanvas = createGraphCanvas();
        //add (graphCanvas,gbc1);
        add("Center",graphCanvas);
        System.out.println("list ps before validate"+list.getPreferredSize());
        list.validate();
        this.validate();
        System.out.println("list ps after validate"+list.getPreferredSize());
        System.out.println(((Object)list).toString());
        System.out.println("\n\n");
    }


    protected Canvas createGraphCanvas()  {
          Canvas gc = new Canvas();
        gc.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        gc.setSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        System.out.println("PC size "+gc.size());
        return gc;
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
    protected static void createAndShowGUI() {
            Frame f = new Frame();
            f.setSize(600, 400);
            Zap pp = new Zap();
            f.add(pp);
            pp.init();
            System.out.println("pack");
        //f.pack();
            System.out.println("setVis");
            f.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("setVis done");
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) *"List next to a Canvas"*  Use a `JList` and a `JPanel` (or `BufferedImage` in a `JLabel`).  In other words, use Swing. 2) Develop the GUI in a panel (`JPanel`) that is added to a frame or applet, rather than in an applet that is added to a frame.

Comment: String[][] equations is about JTable :-)

Comment: Yes I guess Swing would solve it easily, I'm kind of curious as to the awt problem though.

Comment: *"I'm kind of curious as to the awt problem though."*  Why?  Note that I saw a working version of that code in Swing, there my interest in the AWT version vanished.  If it was a bug, you reported it & it was accepted as a bug in the [bug database](http://bugs.sun.com/), I doubt many people would notice it, let alone vote for it.

Comment: That GUI would be better suited to a tree like structure for the formulas, holding objects of `TitledFormula` (or something good) that encapsulates the title & formula.

Comment: Might be an idea. Looks like there wont be a quick bug fix in awt so I'll have to redo the full application in swing. Don't really want a JTable as I only want to display a title and store the other data somewhere convenient.

Comment: I guess I won't find an easy awt bug fix and will need to convert full application to swing. JTable isn't really what I want as I only want to display the first item in each row and store the other items somewhere handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (Swing based) variant of the list.

[image: Zap]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Zap extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 330L;

    String[][] equations = new String[][]{
            //                  {"Line ----------------------","3 t-1","t+1"},
            {"Line","3 t-1","t+1"},
            {"Circle","cos(t)","sin(t)","-pi","pi"},
            {"Sq Circle","cos(t)","2 sin(t)","-pi","pi"},
            {"Ellipse","2 cos(t)","sin(t)","-pi","pi"},
            {"Cycloid","t-sin(t)","1-cos(t)","-20","20"},
            {"---- Hypocycloids ----"},
            {"Deltoid","2 cos(t)+cos(2t)","2 sin(t)-sin(2t)","-pi","pi"},
            {"Astroid","cos(t)^3","sin(t)^3","-pi","pi"},
            {"Hypocycloids 5","cos(t) + cos(4 t)/4","sin(t) - sin(4 t)/4","-pi","pi" },
            {"---- Epicycloids ----"},
            {"Cardioid",
                "cos(t) - cos(2 t)/2",
                "sin(t) - sin(2 t)/2","-pi","pi" },
                {"Nephroid",
                    "cos(t) - cos(3 t)/3",
                    "sin(t) - sin(3 t)/3","-pi","pi" },
                    {"Epicycloid 3",
                        "cos(t) - cos(4 t)/4",
                        "sin(t) - sin(4 t)/4","-pi","pi" },
                        {"Epicycloid 4",
                            "cos(t) - cos(5 t)/5",
                            "sin(t) - sin(5 t)/5","-pi","pi" },
                            {"Epicycloid 4",
                                "cos(t) - cos(5 t)/5",
                                "sin(t) - sin(5 t)/5","-pi","pi" },
                                {"Epicycloid 5",
                                    "cos(t) - cos(6 t)/6",
                                    "sin(t) - sin(6 t)/6","-pi","pi" },

                                    {"---- Lissajous curves ----","t","t","1","1"}, // commenting this line
                                    {"Lissajous 1,2","sin(t)","sin(2 t)","-pi","pi"},
                                    {"Lissajous 1,3","sin(t-pi/2)","sin(3 t)","-pi","pi"},
                                    {"Lissajous 1,4","sin(t)","sin(4 t)","-pi","pi"},//             {"a Lissajousxxxxxxxxxxb",""},
                                    {"Lissajous 2,1","sin(2t)","sin(t)","-pi","pi"},
                                    {"Lissajous 2,2","sin(2t-pi/4)","sin(2t)","-pi","pi"},
                                    {"Lissajous 2,3","sin(2t-pi/3)","sin(3t)","-pi","pi"},
                                    {"Lissajous 3,4","sin(3t)","sin(4t)","-pi","pi"},
    };

    /** The canvas for plotting the graph */
    private JPanel graphCanvas;

    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel(); 
    /** List of equations */
    JList list = new JList(model);

    /**
     * Initializes the FunctionPlotter
     */
    public void init ()  {
        try {
            initComponents();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the layout of the applet window to BorderLayout, creates all
     * the components and associates them with event listeners if necessary.
     * @param j
     * @throws JepException
     */
    private void initComponents ()  {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        System.out.println("list "+list.getBounds());
        System.out.println("list ps"+list.getPreferredSize());
        list.setVisibleRowCount(8);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(
                list, 
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER
                );
        add(BorderLayout.LINE_END,scroll);

        for(String[] eles:equations) {
            model.addElement(eles[0]);
        }

        // create the graph canvas and add it
        graphCanvas = createGraphCanvas();
        //add (graphCanvas,gbc1);
        add("Center",graphCanvas);
    }

    protected JPanel createGraphCanvas()  {
        JPanel gc = new JPanel() {

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN.darker());
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
        };

        gc.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,10));
        return gc;
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
    protected static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        Zap pp = new Zap();
        f.add(pp);
        pp.init();
        System.out.println("pack");
        f.pack();
        System.out.println("setVis");
        f.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("setVis done");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep I've now converted to swing. Less painful than expected.